# How to insert grouped value from Multi-index dataframe into each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Multiindex dataframe [image]

that I created by using .pivot() and .swaplevel() methods:

```
df4 = test.pivot(index=['Company', 'EmployeeName', 'ID', 'Position', 'SortCenterOperationType', 'WeightGroup', 'Tarif', 'Hub', 'Cluster'],
             columns='Date', values=['OperationQty', 'faults', 'table_hours', 'hours_for_payment', 'Payment']
            ).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(1).reindex(level = 1, columns = ['table_hours', 'hours_for_payment', 'faults', 'OperationQty' , 'Payment'])
```

But I want this df to have each one of the grouped row as a individual row (keeping the multi-index header on the right.
How could I get it to be more like this?
[image]

I have the idea how I can keep the multi-index with

```
([[''], ['Company']],
[[''], ['Name']],
[[''], ['ID']].....)
```

But I don't know how to replicate grouped value into each row cell.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've found the solution!

```
df.reset_index()
```

Works very well in this situation